# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'name' can't be used to index type "object"

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { RestoService } from '../resto.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-resto',
  templateUrl: './update-resto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-resto.component.css']
})
export class UpdateRestoComponent implements OnInit {
 editResto = new FormGroup({
   name : new FormControl(''),
   email : new FormControl(''),
   address : new FormControl('')
 })
  constructor(private router : ActivatedRoute, private resto:RestoService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resto.getCurrentResto(this.router.snapshot.params.id)
    .subscribe(res=> {
      this.editResto = new FormGroup({
        name : new FormControl**(res['name']),**
        email : new FormControl**(res['email']),**
        address : new FormControl**(res['address'])**
      })
    })
  }

}
```

the error between the astrisk ** **
property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'
property 'email' does not exist on type 'object'
property 'address**strong text**' does not exist on type 'object'

Comment: And the question is? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: And what is with all those unrelated tags? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is actually a typescript question. Either temporarily set the type of res to any `((res:any)=>..` or better yet create a type called person and set res to type person. I'd advise you to read a bit about typescript and its benefits before diving too deep into Angular, this is part of the basics of typescript

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCurrentResto` observable doesn't have a type. I'm assuming it's an http response. You can type http requests like so: `http.get<Resto>('url')`

Please refer to the Angular http guide for more info https://angular.io/guide/http